# Baby Rudin's 1.35 (Schwarz inequality)

Tags: analysis, proof-explanation

> If $a_1,...,a_n$ and $b_1,...,b_n$ are complex numbers then
>
> $$|\sum_{j=1}^na_j\overline{b_j}|^2 \leq
>  \sum_{j=1}^n|a_j|^2\sum_{j=1}^n|b_j|^2$$
>
> Proof: Put $A=\sum_{j=1}^n|a_j|^2$, $B=\sum_{j=1}^n|b_j|^2$,
>    $C=\sum_{j=1}^na_j\overline{b_j}$. If $B=0$, then $b_1=...=b_n = 0$
>   and the conclusion is trivial. Assume therefore that $B \gt 0$. Then
>   we have
>
> $$\sum_{j=1}^n|Ba_j-Cb_j|^2 =
>  \sum_{j=1}^n(Ba_j-Cb_j)(B\overline{a_j}-\overline{Cb_j}) $$
>
> $$=
>  B^2\sum_{j=1}^n|a_j|^2-B\overline{C}\sum_{j=1}^na_j\overline{b_j}-BC\sum_{j=1}^n\overline{a_j}b_j+|C|^2\sum_{j=1}^n|b_j|^2$$
>
> $$= B^2A-B|C|^2$$
>
> $$(...)$$

How did $-B\overline{C}\sum_{j=1}^na_j\overline{b_j}-BC\sum_{j=1}^n\overline{a_j}b_j$ disappear? Why is it always $0$?

Comment: It does not disappear – otherwise the answer would be $B^2 A + B |C|^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
 &B^2\sum_{j=1}^n|a_j|^2-B\overline{C}\sum_{j=1}^na_j\overline{b_j}-BC\sum_{j=1}^n\overline{a_j}b_j+|C|^2\sum_{j=1}^n|b_j|^2
&\\
&=B^2A-B\overline{C}C-BC\overline{C}+|C|^2B\\
&=B^2A-2B|C|^2+|C|^2B
\\&= B^2A-B|C|^2\end{align}